# Most efficient way to find points on line with polar representation

Tags: python, hough-transform

I have `rho`, `theta` representing the line (found by hough transform):

```
rho = x cos(theta) + y sin(theta)
```

What is the most pythonic and efficient way to get two cartesian points (within image bounds if possible) from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_points_on_polar_line(rho,theta):
    a=np.cos(theta)
    b=np.sin(theta)
    x0=np.array((rho * a, rho * b))
    return (x0,x0+(-b, a))
```